# What's the best way to fit this very strange-looking data?

Tags: curve-fitting

[image]

Hi all,

Could anybody please help me?

I am trying to learn if there is any good approach in modern statistics that can fit this data well, without over-fitting.

Ok, here is another plot that I used "pch=".""... thanks for pointing that out to me!

[image]

Here is a 3D one: again, I want to be able to classify the {positive, negative}-ness of the z-axis...

[image]

Comment: If this is done in $R$, you should try replotting it with `plot(...,pch=".")`. That is a quick-and-dirty way to see the density of the points better.

Comment: Can you say more about what you're trying to do? I suppose you're trying to use the variable on the $x$-axis to predict the variable on the $y$-axis but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes, I am trying to do some predicting... especially I would like to figure out how to classify the folks on the y-axis into {positive, negative} classes... Thank you for asking!

Comment: The folks on the $y$-axis? Each data point has both an $x$ and $y$ coordinate (and are apparently corresponding to individuals) so there's nobody on the $y$-axis who isn't also on the $x$-axis. What defines positive/negative? Absolute value of their $y$ measurement?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I meant that I want to use the x values to predict/classify whether the y values will be positive or negative... This is a scatter plot, i.e. I plotted y vs. x ... The simplest one can be a linear regression, but I guess that's probably not the best way to do this ... I am also thinking of one more dimension/data-set, so that I can use x and y to predict/classify z. I guess before I move to high dimensional fitting, I'd better learn to do the above "simpler" things well. Thank you!

Comment: For binary classification, the simplest thing you can do is logistic regression - have you tried that? Is $z$ a continuous or categorical variable?

Comment: I'd just add that this isn't *particularly* strange looking data.  However, two points of interest: a) the horizontal lines suggest that there is some grouping at particular measurements of the x axis (eg rounding or some similar measurement issue) b) the tentacles" of data towards the right appear to have some kind of correlation with eachother.  I'd suspect they are multiple observations on the same subject at different times (which means they are autocorrelated and hence something to deal with before fitting a regression) but this doesn't quite fit your description in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Macro - z in the 3d plot and y in the 2d plot above are continuous...

Comment: Thanks Peter - indeed you are right - these samples are taking along the time... i.e. I sampled x, y and z every day... How do I deal with them before fitting? I am thinking of doing some SVM, etc. But I will try Macro's idea of logistic regression first... Is there a package in R for logistic regression (along with other fitting commands) which includes the cross-validation, so that I don't have to write my own cross-validation routines? Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that when you plot 2 independent but skewed variables against each other it can look like there is a relationship when there is not one (similar to your plots above).  I would start by using the techniques outlined in:

> ```
>  Buja, A., Cook, D. Hofmann, H., Lawrence, M. Lee, E.-K., Swayne,
>  D.F and Wickham, H. (2009) Statistical Inference for exploratory
>  data analysis and model diagnostics Phil. Trans. R. Soc. A 2009
>  367, 4361-4383 doi: 10.1098/rsta.2009.0120
> ```

The `vis.test` function in the TeachingDemos package for R implements this test (or it is not that hard to do on you own using other tools).

If you cannot tell your data from permuted data using this method then any model you try to fit to the data will be overfitting.  If there is enough of a relationship that you can see it here, then use the techniques others have mentioned (though with the skewness you may want to look at log transforms or other BoxCox transforms of your data).

Also, is every point in the above plot from a different subject?  There seem to be some possible curves coming out of the main plot that look like they could be multiple measumerments over time from a single subject.  If you have multiple measurements/points per subject with several subjects in the data, then that will also complicate any analysis, you will probably need to look at mixed effects models in that case.

Comment: I spotted the same issue of the curves coming out of the main plot - if you follow the comments trail the OP confirmed that they are multiple measurements.

Answer (score 0):

You can start just by fitting a simple linear regression:

```
model <- lm( y~x, data=... )
```

Then you definitely wouldn't have to worry about overfitting :-). After this, you want to look into the poly() function. I doubt at this stage you would want to try very complicated equations. I'm not sure what else to suggest without knowing more information, such as if there is a known classification you would like to train with or if there are more variables available for fitting.

Comment: maybe I should try SVM, by dividing this dataset into in-sample and out-sample? Or may I should try leave-K-out, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you just wont "to be able to classify the {positive, negative}-ness of the z-axis" within a probabilistic framework, then Gaussian Process Classification (GPC) may help you. SVM are ok, but you will find that SVM are sometimes just a special case of GPC. A useful reference manual is [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW3.pdf), Carl Edward Rasmussen and Chris Williams, the MIT Press, 2006